# Soft interactions at high energy hadron-hadron collision?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm reading Peskin&Schoeder and in the section 17.4 (p.563) it says:

"If one collides hadrons with other hadrons at very high energy, most of the collisions will involve only soft interactions of the constituent quarks and gluons."

Which implies small momentum transfer so big coupling thus perturbative qcd is not applicable.

I don't really understand this because it is a high energy collision and the energy transfer should be big (?).

Comment: "Most" indicates highly likely, so with big couplings selected in, and small couplings selected out.

Comment: "High energy collision" means simply that the energy of the hadron beam(s) is high (i.e. at least several GeVs). In the collision it the most cases anyway only a small part of the initial energy is transferred between the hadrons. When the energy transfer is small, it's not possible to apply perturbative theory because the strong coupling constant is big.